# python 16 bit 32 bit two's complement

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, arithmetic-expressions

### Two 16-bit unsigned registers into 32-bit signed number and back to 2 16-bit registers

I have a register on a device that spawns two consecutive registry cells.  Both of these cells contain a 16-bit unsigned integer.  Ie:

```
    [3361, 0]
    [2399, 0]
    [64565, 65535]
```

As you can see, sometimes they need to be deciphered as signed 32-bit integer numbers and then potentially stored back to the registries after manipulation.

What is the proper way to handle this issue in Python3.2?

I've seen struct.packs, numpies, c_types, and even standard bit switching procedures, but what is the standard, supported way to achieve this?

An example would be nice, thank you.

Comment: Do you have any code of what you have tried? I'm still a little unsure of what you are asking.

Comment: There is no single, standard, supported way to achieve this.  You are giving four examples of how to do it already, pick one which suits you best.

Comment: whatever you choose to implement the access, start by creating a simple class to abstract away from the hardware. when you have used it a bit you may decide on a better implementation, but you wont have to change all your code using the class. that's the python way.